# How to include objects[ids] only when fetching all records in Parse [Swift]

Tags: swift, parse-server, swift5, back4app

In Parse Server, say I have School class, which has courses relation.
as shown in the picture

[image: Parse Server School class]

What I want here is to get all schools including the courses relation. BUT, it should NOT include all columns of Course class. only objectId column.

Reason:
for performance. I want to get all schools with courses ids of every school, to **count** them. If i loaded the whole Course object, the query maybe gets slow.

This is my code:

```swift
        // create query
        let query = PFQuery(className:"School")        

        query.includeKey("Courses")
        query.limit = 50

        query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.networkElseCache
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error)-> Void in

            if error == nil {

                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) school.")


                // TODO: get courses count


            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!)")
            }
        }
```

So, I need to get the courses count of every school without loading the whole course objects, only loading objectIds of courses, to make the query super fast

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to include the objects of a relation field in a query (only pointers). If you want to retrieve with a single query, you will need to write a cloud code function and use aggregate to perform this task.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thanks. any source link for the method you mentioned?

Comment: Yes. You can learn more about aggregate here: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate

Comment: thanks @DaviMacêdo